# Update Strategy with DD_INSERT

Tags: mapping, transformation, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Why we use Update Strategy transformation with DD_INSERT however Informatica automatically inserts the data without Update strategy transformation?

expecting the answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a tool - and many logic demands different kind of behavior.
Your assumptions `Informatica automatically inserts the data` is for default behavior with all settings left as default. If someone wants to insert, update, delete, reject - they can use different options in update strategy. You also need to set the session to data driven.

If you put only dd_insert, this means this pipeline is used only for inserting.

Comment: Thanks Koushik , My doubt is when Informatica do the job of inserting records by default then why we need to use update strategy with DD_INSERT, it will increase performance of session or what

Comment: if you think `update strategy with DD_INSERT` with all default settings are useless. But in case someone has different default settings/someone overwrote some settings, your session will be messed up. so best is to be sure and you can add logic to run update etc later.

Answer (score 0):

If a mapping performs single type of operation AND it's not driven by the data, then `Update Strategy` transformation is not at all required.

And it's not even for inserts only, as this is driven by the `Treat input rows as` session property [[more information can be found here](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/workflow-basics-guide/sources/working-with-relational-sources/defining-the-treat-source-rows-as-property.html)].

Furthermore, it's possible to specify general approach for the whole session and then override it for particular targets, if needed. Still without using `Update Strategy` transformation.